# Why does adding 'sort(key=len,reverse=True))' to list change output of function from list to None

Tags: python

When I run this:

```
def get_substring(str_name,k):
    str_list = []
    for i in reversed(range(len(str_name)+1)):
        for index,x in enumerate(str_name):
            str_list.append(str_name[index:index+i])

    filtered_list = list(filter(None,str_list))
    return filtered_list
```

The output is:

```
['abcba', 'bcba', 'cba', 'ba', 'a', 'abcb', 'bcba', 'cba', 'ba', 'a', 'abc', 'bcb', 'cba', 'ba', 'a', 'ab', 'bc', 'cb', 'ba', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'a']
```

I want to return a sorted list, so the list is returned with the longest strings first, but when I run this:

```
def get_substring(str_name,k):
    str_list = []
    for i in reversed(range(len(str_name)+1)):
        for index,x in enumerate(str_name):
            str_list.append(str_name[index:index+i])

    filtered_list = list(filter(None,str_list)).sort(key=len,reverse=True)
    return filtered_list    


print(get_substring('abcba', 2)) #.sort(key=len,reverse=True))
```

The output is just 'None'.

Why is this? Can I not sort the list in the function?

Comment: Because `sort` returns None.

Comment: `sort()` changes original list and it doesn't return new list but `None` (it is called "in place" operation) . You need `filtered_list = sorted(list, key, ...)`